# Salesforce Chat

Tags: liveagent, chat, snap-ins

I am trying to enable queuing for chats (embedded/snapins chat). I have setup a max queue to 4 (for testing).

I don't see a way to stop accepting any new chat requests to be queued at a certain time (say at end of shift for the contact center).

I need the ability to stop accepting any new chat requests after  5 PM, but an agent (the last one in the shift) should still be able to accept the chat requests that are already in queue.

I imagine this would be a standard feature for any contact center product.

Am I missing any other settings or is this a product limitation?

If it is a product limitation has body implemented a workaround?